# Как упростить запрос mysql?

Tags: mysql, инспекция-кода

Подскажите как упростить/оптимизировать запрос.
Смущает количество JOINов. Не будет ли это слишком ресурсоемкий запрос?

```
CREATE TABLE `board` (
    `id` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID Объявления',
    `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Название Объявления',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO `board` VALUES
(100, 'Продам Daewoo'),
(101, 'Продам Kia'),
(102, 'Продам Ford');

CREATE TABLE `options` (
    `item_id` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID Объявления',
    `option_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Название параметра',
    `value` varchar(200) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Значение параметра',
    KEY `item_id` (`item_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO `options` VALUES
(100, 'model', 'Lanos'),
(100, 'color', 'Бежевый'),
(100, 'cond', 'Новый'),
(101, 'model', 'Rio'),
(101, 'color', 'Синий'),
(101, 'cond', 'Б/у'),
(102, 'model', 'Transit'),
(102, 'cond', 'Новый');
```

Сам запрос:

```
SELECT b.id,b.name FROM board as b
JOIN options as o1 ON o1.item_id = b.id && o1.option_id = 'model' && o1.value IN ('Lanos','Transit','Rio')
JOIN options as o2 ON o2.item_id = b.id && o2.option_id = 'color' && o2.value IN ('Синий')
JOIN options as o3 ON o3.item_id = b.id && o3.option_id = 'cond' && o3.value IN ('Б/у')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/245ed3/246

Comment: Старайтесь размещать код прямо в вопросе, это увеличит вероятность ответа другими участниками.

Comment: Прочитайте пожалуйста описание метки "инспекция-кода" (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0/info), а также, попробуйте дать вопросу более толковое название.

Comment: По идее запрос улучшить не получится — для EAV в SQL такие JOIN'ы — нормальная практика... при желании можно заменить их на подзапросы но погоды это, скорей всего, не сделает... а вот индекс по первым двум (или даже всем трём) колонкам на `options` необходим... хотя, может быть, лучше будет наоборот сделать индекс по `(option_id, value)`, а `options.item_id` сделать  нормальным внешним ключом... но тут в планировщике надо смотреть, что лучше будет...